# Matplotlib Running Out of Memory When Adding Lots of Image Thumbnails to the Figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm trying to make a very large 2D image containing lots of embeddings like the one in the [UMAP Explorer project](https://grantcuster.github.io/umap-explorer/):

[image]

I'm using a code like this:

```
def getImage(path, width=100, zoom=1.0):
        image = plt.imread(path)
        image = imutils.resize(image, width=width)
        return OffsetImage(image, zoom=zoom)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)

ax.scatter(
    embeddings[:, 0],
    embeddings[:, 1])

for x, y, path in zip(embeddings[:, 0], embeddings[:, 1], image_paths):
    ab = AnnotationBbox(getImage(path, width=1024, zoom=0.005), (x, y), frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)
```

The code runs fine until there are more images than the available memory. It seems that Matplotlib does not finalize/rasterize each image on the figure and keeps track of the allocated images until there isn't any more remaining memory.

Is there a way to be able to add as many images as I want and it is rasterized inside the figure without running out of memory?